# Figuring out the target MacOS SDK version in CMake?

Tags: macos, cmake, version, target

I have code that I want to conditionally compile depending on the target SDK version, so that I can use newer features if possible.  This can be done by checking the `__MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED` macro, which tells us the target SDK version, in the source code.

Typically, performing conditional compilation on that macro suffices, and everything is nice and good.  However, when targeting a newer SDK version, I would like to use features from a new library (specifically the UniformTypeIdentifiers library) that is not available on an older SDK version.  This means that the `target_link_libraries()` in CMake has to account for this, i.e. link the new library if targeting a newer SDK version, and skip the new library otherwise.

I can't seem to find any way to figure out the target SDK version in CMake.  What is the proper way to do this?

Things I have tried:

1. Checking `CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET`.  This flag is what CMake uses to pass the `-mmacosx-version-min` flag to clang, that makes it use a particular deployment target.  However, it turns out that this may not necessarily be defined.  When not defined, clang doesn't get the flag, but since clang is given something like `-isysroot /Applications/Xcode-13.3.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk`, the framework sets `__MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED` to something default (12.3), and so the source code is able to still perform conditional compilation.
2. Checking if the library exists by using `find_library()` (e.g. `find_library(UNIFORMTYPEIDENTIFIERS_LIBRARY UniformTypeIdentifiers)`).  This does not work when users want to target a lower version (e.g. by setting `CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET`), since the new library will still exist.

Essentially, I would like a way for CMake to figure out the deployment target that ultimately gets chosen (i.e. something equivalent to `__MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED`), so that it can decide whether or not to link with the new library.

How should I do this?

---

Context:

I'm trying to resolve an issue in my library [here](https://github.com/btzy/nativefiledialog-extended/pull/72).

I also have a [testing branch](https://github.com/btzy/nativefiledialog-extended/tree/testing-ci-flags) set up to check `CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` and the compiler command in the CI builds: GitHub CI builds MacOS 10.15 (without the new library, with CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET) and 11 (with the new library, with CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET), and Circle CI builds MacOS 12 (with the new library, but without CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET).

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to determine this via some CMake variable, so I rolled by own compilation test for it:

```
include(CheckCXXSourceCompiles)
check_cxx_source_compiles(
  "
  #include <Availability.h>
  #if !defined(__MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED) || !defined(__MAC_11_0) || __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < __MAC_11_0
  static_assert(false);
  #endif
  int main() { return 0; }
  "
  NFD_USE_ALLOWEDCONTENTTYPES
)
```

This ensures full consistency with the check in the source code, at the cost of a slightly longer time to configure the build.